# Surface and volumes of solids of revolution

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

The lemniscate $\ r^2 =\ a^2 \cos (2\theta) $ revolves about a tangent at the pole. What will be the volume generated?

I know the answer will be $ \frac  {\pi a^3}{4}$
But my question is how?
Any help possible is requested.

Comment: Do you know how to determine the volume of a rotated graph?

Comment: Yes I do @MichaelParis

Comment: I've obtained $\frac{\pi^2a^3}{4}$.

Comment: Would you like to show what you have done?

Comment: I actually have not got access to a camera...pretty difficult for me MathJax so much..but thanx anyways@MichaelParis

Comment: I've found other solutions here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362582/volume-of-lemniscate-rotated-using-high-school-methods/2364121

Comment: and that one very similar which confirms the result https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941603/volume-generated-by-lemniscate-revolving-about-a-tangent-at-the-pole

Comment: @ShukradityaBose Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

We have that the area of a lemniscate is

$$A=2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\int r^2d\theta\right)=a^2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(2\theta)d {\theta}=a^2$$

the centroid of an half is located at $(x_C,0)$ with

$$x_C=\frac{\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac23 r\,\cos\theta\, r^2d\theta}{a^2/2}=\frac23a\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos\theta\ \cos^\frac32(2\theta) \,d\theta=\frac23a\frac{3\pi}{8\sqrt 2}=\frac{\sqrt 2\pi}{8}a$$

[integral evaluation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20cosx(cos2x)%5E(3%2F2)%20dx%20x%3D-pi%2F4..pi%2F4)

then by Pappus theorem

$$V=2\pi R\cdot A=2\pi \left(x_C\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)\cdot a^2=2\pi\left(\frac{\sqrt 2\pi}{8}a\frac{\sqrt 2}2\right)a^2=\frac{\pi^2a^3}{4}$$

Comment: It seems to me that you are revolving the **entire** lemniscate (e.g., a figure 8) around the $y$-axis. Thus you are actually counting the volume twice Do you think that's the desired answer? Who would pose such a problem?

Comment: @CyeWaldman Yes of course it is referred to the full lemniscate but around the tangent to the pole that is the line $y=x$. See also the linked OP.

Comment: I appreciate pointing out my error. But if I visualize rotating the axis by $\pi/4$ then your calculation of the centroid is incorrect. I think it would be $a\cdot \pi/8$.   Aha, I see that you corrected it $\sqrt{2}/2$. Okay, all is good. Thanks.

Comment: @CyeWaldman Yes indeed, I've calculated $x_C$ and then calculated the radius to apply Pappus theorem. You are welcome! Bye